# Set an automatic DateTime.Now value for an @Html.HiddenFor

Tags: c#, validation, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to ask is there any way to set an automatic `DateTime.Now` value for properties `ENTRY_DATE` and `AUDIT_TIME` in the `Create()` HttpPost method? The form is created and it works fine. If the DateTime is inserted manually. But, it won't work if I set an automatic value and would run into a

> "One or more validation Error's"..

This is my model (I don't understand how to make a viewmodel) :

```
public partial class TRRESPONDENT
{
    public TRRESPONDENT()
    {
        this.TRFOLLOWUPRESPONDENTs = new HashSet<TRFOLLOWUPRESPONDENT>();
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Respondent ID is required!")]
    [Display(Name = "Respondent ID")]
    public string RESPONDENT_ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a BINUS Center!")]
    [Display(Name = "Binus Center")]
    public string BC_ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be empty!")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [StringLength(100,ErrorMessage = "Name length cannot be more than 100 characters!")]
    public string FULL_NAME { get; set; }
    .... // more properties
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please pick a City Location!")]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public int CITY_ID { get; set; }
    // The following 2 properties need to be set
    [Display(Name = "Entry Date")]
    public DateTime ENTRY_DATE { get; set; }
    public DateTime AUDIT_TIME { get; set; }
    .... 
    public virtual LTCITY LTCITY { get; set; }
    public virtual LTSOURCERESPONDENT LTSOURCERESPONDENT { get; set; }
    public virtual MSBINUSCENTER MSBINUSCENTER { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TRFOLLOWUPRESPONDENT> TRFOLLOWUPRESPONDENTs { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RESPONDENT_ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RESPONDENT_ID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RESPONDENT_ID)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BC_ID, "Binus Center")
    @Html.DropDownList("BC_ID", null)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BC_ID)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FULL_NAME)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FULL_NAME)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FULL_NAME)

    .... // more form controls

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CITY_ID, "City")
    @Html.DropDownList("CITY_ID", null)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CITY_ID)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ENTRY_DATE)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AUDIT_TIME)

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

This is my controller :

```
public class RespondentController : Controller
{
    private RespondentBINUSEntities db = new RespondentBINUSEntities();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CITY_ID = new SelectList(db.LTCITies, "CITY_ID", "CITY_NAME", 1);
        var entry = new Models.TRRESPONDENT
        {
            ENTRY_DATE = DateTime.Now,
            AUDIT_TIME = DateTime.Now,
        };
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RESPONDENT_ID,BC_ID,BINUSIAN_ID,FULL_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,ADDRESS,CITY_ID,ZIP_CODE,SOURCE_ID,ENTRY_DATE,PACKAGE,AUDIT_USER_NAME,AUDIT_TIME,AUDIT_ACTIVITY")] TRRESPONDENT tRRESPONDENT)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TRRESPONDENTs.Add(tRRESPONDENT);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CITY_ID = new SelectList(db.LTCITies, "CITY_ID", "CITY_NAME", tRRESPONDENT.CITY_ID);
        return View(tRRESPONDENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get that validation error during `SaveChanges()` method? What kind of `DateTime.Now` automatic value looks like?

Comment: You should not be doing that. The value of that property should be set in the controller immediately before you save the object.

Comment: yes! when it runs into the db.SaveChanges(), it got error. But if I try to catch the error log with try-catch, the error would occur when I 'throw' the error log.

Comment: Show the error details there. As Stephen said, property values should be set in controller before passing to `SaveChanges()` method, or use `KeyAttribute` if `no keys defined` error has encountered.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I've tried to set the value at controller and/or in my model. But it won't work. It just circle around in my Create form

Comment: Does the date need to be part of the form if it's always DateTime.Now? Couldn't it be added to the data after it has been posted?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The error will occur if I set @Value inside my form. But, if I set it in controller and/or model, it would just return my Create form over and over again and would not save changes to my database

Comment: You need to add your code in the question. We cannot guess what mistake you have made (and do not include that property in the form as I noted in your previous question)

Comment: It has to be. It should be inserted to the database alongside with the data that the user input

Comment: _has to be what!_ Show your code!

Comment: Since your error related to datetime, I have thoughts with common `The field XXX must be a date` error. However, without detailed code it is hard to tell where the validation error comes from.

Comment: I have updated the post, guys. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Now you have just dumpled all your code (90% of which is irrelevant to the question). Which method are you referring to? And which property (I assume its `public DateTime ENTRY_DATE { get; set; }`?)

Comment: Well, I see that `ENTRY_DATE` and `AUDIT_TIME` field declared as `DateTime` which may filled with current datetime, but which `SaveChanges()` method exactly throwing validation error? I suspected usage of `EntityState.Modified` triggering it.

Comment: yes. the property that I'm trying to preset the value is ENTRY_DATE and AUDIT_TIME, Stephen.

So, what am I supposed to do, Tetsuya?

Comment: Can you share the error which you are getting while saving the changes?

Comment: Give me 30 min and I will add an answer (and edit your question)

Comment: There are 3 `SaveChanges()` method on your code, which one triggered the validation error? If it is `Edit` method, just change the value and save changes made with it (e.g. `ENTRY_DATE = DateTime.Now`), don't re-set the entire entity state as modified one.

Comment: Chetan, I don't get the error now. But, I'm only circling around in my Create form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stephen. Really appreciated it.

I'm working on the create method, Tetsuya..

Comment: I don't see any `KeyAttribute` defined there, but it has `HashSet<TRFOLLOWUPRESPONDENT>` and `ICollection<TRFOLLOWUPRESPONDENT>` which signs Entity Framework model may being used. Could it be `EntityType has no key defined` error? If it's true, just set `KeyAttribute` on `RESPONDENT_ID` and works fine then.

Comment: @SionChristian, I have added an answer to solve the immediate issue, but I will edit this in a few hours to show how your view model should look, and the associated controller methods

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. I really appreciated it. 
Anyway, do you know how we can generate something like a unique code based on user's selected values? For example if user registers at a dropdownlist that has a value of XBC3, and create it on 2017, then the unique code will be generated maybe like, RXBC3201700010?

Comment: You need to ask anew question for that (and showing a bit more detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not stated the details of the error message, but no doubt this is because you saving a values of `01/01/0001` to a field which which is `DATETIME` (which only accepts dates between `01/01/1753` to `12/31/9999`) and not `DATETIME2`.

The reason the values of you dates are `01/01/0001` (which is the default for `DateTime`) is because you do not pass a model to the view so default values are used. The code in your GET  needs to be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CITY_ID = new SelectList(db.LTCITies, "CITY_ID", "CITY_NAME", 1);
    var entry = new Models.TRRESPONDENT
    {
        ENTRY_DATE = DateTime.Now,
        AUDIT_TIME = DateTime.Now,
    };
    return View(entry); // return your model
}
```

However you should not use your data model in the view, and instead create a view model containing only the properties you need. Values such as `ENTRY_DATE` should only be set immediately before you save the data model to the database. For information on a creating a view model, refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc).

---

The basic steps for creating a view model are

1. Create a new folder (say) `ViewModels` and copy you data model to and
   and rename it (say)`RespondentVM`
2. Delete all the `[Display]` attributes from you data model (they are
   view specific attributes)
3. Delete all the properties which the user will not be editing in the
   view (e.g `ENTRY_DATE` and `AUDIT_TIME`) except the property which
   is the objects ID which should be renamed to `ID` so its
   automatically bound assuming your using the default routes (note its
   not clear if you even have an ID property - I assume its
   `RESPONDENT_ID`, but that should be an auto-incremented `int` in the
   database -i.e. `[Key]public int RespondentId { get; set; }`). I also
   recommend you rename all your properties to follow naming
   conventions - `EntryDate`, not `ENTRY_DATE`.
4. Change all value types to be `nullable` and add the `[Required]`
   attribute to protect against under-posting attacks (e.g. `public int
   CITY_ID { get; set; }` becomes `public int? CityID { get; set; }`
5. Add additional properties for `SelectList`'s etc that you are
   currently assigning to `ViewBag` properties, e.g. `public
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CityList { get; set; }`

You controller methods will then be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    RespondentVM model = new RespondentVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(RespondentVM model) // note a [Bind]` attribute is not required
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // Initialize an instance of your data model and set its properties based on the view model
    TRRESPONDENT respondent = new TRRESPONDENT()
    {
        FULL_NAME = model.FullName,
        CITY_ID = model.CityID,
        ....
        // Set default values
        ENTRY_DATE = DateTime.Now,
        ....
    }
    db.TRRESPONDENTs.Add(respondent);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

// Common code for populating SelectLists etc - DRY!
private void ConfigureviewModel(RespondentVM model)
{
    // Note - delete the 4th parameter of the SelectList constructor
    model.CityID = new SelectList(db.LTCITies, "CITY_ID", "CITY_NAME");
}
```

And a few extra notes on your view code.

1. You do not need a hidden input for the ID property if its named `ID`
   and your using the default routing
2. Since you have `[Display(Name = "..")]` attributes, then in the view
   its just `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertyName)`, not
   `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertyName, "some text")`
3. To generate your dropdownlists, use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>
   m.CityID, Model.CityList, "Please select", new { ... });` - you
   current implementation will not give correct 2-way model binding or
   client side validation.

Comment: See update to the question for how to use a view model (which you should always have, especially when editing data)